# Get word frequency using search engines

Tags: api, cpu-word, search-engine, frequency, word-frequency

Are there any good services which can give me the amount of web pages a word occurs on ?

I need this to calculate [Normalized Google Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_Google_distance). A few years ago there was the google web search API which one could call and get the occurrences and the search results(which i don't actually need).

This web search API has now been replaced with google custom search API, but the cost of this service is too high for my purpose.

The Bing Search API and Yahoo! BOSS Search API is not an option either since they only return a max of 50 search results and not an estimate of word occurences.

Already did quite some searching on the internet but i can't seam to find anything which gives me the information i want.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

(Late I know, but I only just found this while trying to solve the same problem)

Maybe a decent substitute would be [Google's Web1T Corpus](http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/catalogEntry.jsp?catalogId=LDC2006T13). It's definitely not perfect for your use case, but it's **probably** better than nothing. In particular, since the corpus only includes 5-grams, the `f(x, y)` counts will only be derivable from words separated by at most three other words, which will most likely mean you'll get counts of zero in many cases, when you would expect a higher count from the actual google results (assuming such as number exists, which as Greg's link told us, it may not). Another potential problem is that it only includes data up to 2006 (you may not care though), and it only includes English (although a [version with 10 European languages](http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/catalogEntry.jsp?catalogId=LDC2009T25) is also available). Oh, and it's $150, which is not obscene, although it could mean you have to deal with the accounts department.

Answer (score 0):

I do it in R using Rcurl

`search_result_adress <- sprintf("http://www.google.com/search?q=%s",searched_expression)
result_page_source_as_string <- getURL(search_result_adress,.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))[[1]]`

Then your result is located in the string between "About" and "results", and I'm too ashamed of my regex skills to display my own solution but i'm sure you'll figure it out :).

the counts of pages are indeed not accurate but you can get more stable results by removing from the search a word that doesn't exist anyway, so google will search harder. I'd tend to trust those more.

exxample searching "character"

> character returns 290,000,000 results.
>
> character -potato returns 931,000,000
>
> character -hincbhjvmzsslzlkjed returns 1,780,000,000
>
> character -zzzanjbedlkjzd returns 1,780,000,000 too, showing a stabilization

for less general queries the estimations are better.

> "google frustrates me" returns 3,920 results.
>
> "google frustrates me" -potato returns 2,870.
>
> "google frustrates me" -hincbhjvmzsslzlkjed returns 2,860.